# how to look at all private variables in a java class with clojure

Tags: clojure

I wish to inspect private fields in java classes using clojure in order to make sense of a big monolithic java application. Is there a library to do this?

Comment: You can use Java reflection API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can access private fields and methods using [clj-wallhack](https://github.com/arohner/clj-wallhack/blob/master/src/wall/hack.clj)

Answer (score 3):

If you want type information (as opposed to runtime state), use `clojure.reflect` to get class reflection represented as a clojure data structure.  E.g.:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.pprint 'clojure.reflect)
nil
user=> (pprint (type-reflect String))
{:bases
 #{java.io.Serializable java.lang.Comparable java.lang.Object
   java.lang.CharSequence},
 :flags #{:public :final},
 :members
 #{{:name equalsIgnoreCase,
    :return-type boolean,
    :declaring-class java.lang.String,
    :parameter-types [java.lang.String],
    :exception-types [],
    :flags #{:public}}
...
```

Comment: Looks like clojure.reflect only works for public methods and fields.